# What is the best way to store a pretty large JSON object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database

I'm building a Laravel app the core features are driven with rather large JSON objects. (the largest ones are between 1000-1500 lines).

I know there are better data base choices than MySQL for storing files and blocks of data, but for various reasons I will need to use MySQL for the application.

So my question is, how to I store my JSON objects most effective in MySQL? I will not need to do any queries on the column that holds the data, there will be other columns for identifying it. Something like this:

id, title, created-at, updated-at, JSON-blobthingy

Any ideas?

Comment: You could go for saving it as TEXT, but I would recommend changing to MongoDB or Redis, as they are designed for document storage rather than relational architectures.

Comment: `LONGTEXT` would help

Comment: @toubou thank you. But I will need to use MySQL, and the rest of the system is based on a relational datamodel.

Comment: @Christoffer oh my God, good luck then :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- You could use the JSON data type if you have MySQL version 5.7.8 or above.
- You could store the JSON file on the server, and simply reference its location via MySQL.
- You could use also one of the [TEXT types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).

Comment: As far as he does not need to do any queries on stored JSON, I would go directly to TEXT type. With caution on not to index that column.

Comment: `LONGTEXT` would help.

Comment: I'm hoping they can update the server to >= 5.7.8. Still though, I don't think I will have to validate the JSON when storing it, since I will validate it through a schema when creating and parsing it. Also I really need a simple slick way of getting it tied into the applications relational structure. So I might go for Text for now. Thank you!

Comment: From the three of these, which one would you use yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can use the type `longblob` which can handle up to 4GB of data for the column holding the large JSON object where you can insert, update, and read this column normally as if it is text or anything else!

Answer (score 1):

The best answer i can give is to use MySQL 5.7. On this version the new column type `JSON` are supported. Which handles large JSON very well (obviously).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

You could compress the data before inserting it if you don't need it searchable. I'm using the 'zlib' library for that